# Уничтожить объект по тегу Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Для коллайдера код выглядит примерно так

```
if (coll.CompareTag("tag"))
    {
        Destroy(coll.gameObject); 
    }
```

А вот если просто необходимо по условию, допустим

```
    if (x == 25)
    {
        if (gameObject.CompareTag("tag1")) { Destroy(gameObject); }

    }
```

Не работает. Т.е. все объекты, на которых висит тег tag1 должны уничтожатся когда x == 25, а этого не происходит. Как сделать чтобы оно работало?
И как сделать, допустим, чтобы объект уничтожался(по тегу) когда перейдет по оси Y допустим 50?

Comment: Хм..... А можно узнать в чем заключается правильность ответа от  господина @анонимно?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский прошу прощения, случайно принял. Вопросу больше 2х месяцев, не разобрался сразу.

Comment: Ну я так-то не против, просто я взглянул, вроде что-то не совсем правильное..... Подумал, если вам помогло - ок... Только и хотел узнать что.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Просто сделайте массив или список объектов с этим тегом, а потом, когда нужно  - удаляйте

```
GameObject[] gameObjects;

function SomeFunction(){     
     gameObjects =  GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("tag1");

     // вместо for можно использовать for (var go in gameObjects)  Destroy(go);
     for(int i = 0; i < gameObjects.Length; ++i) {
         if (gameObjects[i].x == 25 || gameObjects[i].y > 50) 
             Destroy(gameObjects[i]);
     }
}
```

**[FindGameObjectsWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html)** - возвращает список активных GameObject'ов с тегом `tag`.

Объекты можно добавить в массив/лист при старте (а не в методе, каждый раз искать, как выше), а также сделать два метода:

- который будет добавлять вновь созданные на сцене такие объекты в массив. И далее просто где-нибудь в `Update` просто будет вызываться:
- метод, который пробегает массив/список и удаляет <s>неверных</s> ненужных. Конечно метод может иметь аргументы, чтоб удалять по условию

  ```
  function DestroySinners(int x, int y) { 
      ...
      // бежим в цикле по списку, удаляя по условию
      if (go.x == x || go.y > y) {
          ...
      }
      ...
  }
  ```

А также не стоит забывать, что если делать список заранее и добавлять туда динамически, то нужно будет не только вызывать метод `Destroy` но и удалить элемент из списка. А то <s>снег башка попадет, совсэм мертвый будешь</s> получится на сцене ни одного объекта, а в списке тысяча. ПроблЭмка.

Comment: спасибо, однако возникла пара проблем. 
 `for(int i = 0; i < gameObjects.length; ++i)`
так подчёркивает lenght, а вот так не подчёркивает.
 `for(int i = 0; i < gameObjects.Length; ++i)`
Далее, непонятно, как удалять элемент из списка. Если это массив то должен быть заранее указан его размер, тут его нет, значит это ArrayList, верно? У него есть метод `remove`, значит код(там же, в цикле, должен быть такой
`Destroy(gameObjects[i]);
                gameObjects.RemoveAt(i);`

Подчёркивает его красным. Что это и как убрать этот элемент из массива?

Comment: в `length` опечатка да... нужно с заглавной буквы.......чтоб не геморроится с массивом да - можно сделать список. ибо размер массива можно менять, но для этого придется немного дописать функцию ресайза.......подчеркивает красным что именно? вы ведь можете навести мышкой и посмотреть подсказку о том, на что он ругается и даже предложения по исправлению, зачем эта игра в телепатов?))

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'GameObject[]' does not contain a definition for 'RemoveAt' and no extension method 'RemoveAt' accepting a first argument of type 'GameObject[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Dmitrii ну так методы для списка, а у вас массив GameObject. Сделайте список и будет вам счастье

Comment: непонятно. Объявляю `ArrayList goclear`, ну а что с ним дальше то делать? Я могу перенести из `gameObjects` все значения в него в цикле, а мне нужно удалить `gameobjects` вообще. Как это реализовать?

Comment: @Dmitrii не знаю что я непонятного написал... в ответе все написано... вы делаете либо массив, либо список (если не хотите утруждаться с функциями увеличения размера массива) и работаете со списком: в одном методе добавляете в список, в другом удаляете из списка + Destroy.......что здесь может быть непонятного?. Если у вас нет понимания базовых вещей, то увы, я ничем не смогу помочь, извините.

Comment: я принял ответ, спасибо. А непонятно мне как превратить то что у нас есть(это видимо массив объектов) в список.

Comment: @Dmitrii повторю в третий раз. вы делаете **либо** массив, **либо** список ........основы C# подскажут вам что есть метод `.ToList();` для конвертации массива в список....... или `AddRange`....`var lst = new List<GameObject>();
lst.AddRange(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("tag1"));` ...... именно поэтому я вам намекаю на то, что вам нужно в начале выучить основы языка программирования.